# How to fix SearchBar as header of UITableView when scrolling?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview, uisearchbar

I've a TableView with SearchBar inside this, but when I scrolling the list the search bar dismiss of the top bar, and I need scrolling up to search bar appears. I tried several solutions at google and stack overflow, but not solves my problem.

I tried this:

```
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    conteudo = ["Augusto","Luis","Joao","Marina","Taina","Evandra","Miguel","Daniela","Luciano","Patricia","Jose","Vinicius","John","William"]

    currentConteudo = conteudo
    currentConteudo.sort()

    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.tableHeaderView = searchBar
    tableView.estimatedSectionHeaderHeight = 50
    searchBar.delegate = self
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return currentConteudo.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellSearchCustomer")!
    cell.textLabel?.text = currentConteudo[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    return searchBar
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
}
```

Scrolled:

[image]

Not scrolled:

[image]

Storyboard:

[image]

Comment: Do you just want the `searchBar` to be visible all the time?

Comment: yes, it is.....

Comment: @Augusto, you want to scroll search-bar when tableview scroll up.? Or else you want search bar not scroll when tableview scroll up.?

Comment: I want search bar never missing. Scrolling up or down, search bar must be visible all time. Fixed at top

Answer (score 2):

Instead of direct using **UISearchBar** as a tableView header, use a **UISearchController** and add it to *navigationItem.searchController* will fix the issue.

```
fileprivate let searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
```

In **viewDidLoad**

```
searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
searchController.hidesNavigationBarDuringPresentation = false
searchController.obscuresBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
searchController.searchBar.placeholder = "Search"
definesPresentationContext = true
navigationItem.searchController = searchController
```

**UISearchControllerDelegate** let you know start searching:

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    // your search operation
    print("Search text : \(searchController.searchBar.text!)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want the `searchBar` to just be visible all the time, you need to move it above the `tableView` in `storyboard`.  At present it is inside.

[image]

Comment: No, it's can be done using search bar like header view of tableview

Comment: You need to explain more clearly what behaviour you require.

Comment: I follow a tutorials, one this is -> https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4RyhnwIRjpA (At 19 mins), him handle this. But for me not works.